# adding dynamic x-axis lables in android app using android achart engine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to develop an android application to plot a graph using achart engine.
All is fine except i have trouble setting text labels to x-axis dynamically.The only way i can find is through statically assigning the labels during development.Anyone know how i can achieve this?
In my application,i will pull the labels from a mysql database.
Here is part of my code so far:

```
int x[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int y[]={1,4,9,16,25,36};
    int z[]={3,4,6,7,4,3};
            String xaxis[]={"jan","feb","march","april"};

    TimeSeries series=new TimeSeries("line1");
    TimeSeries series2=new TimeSeries("line2");

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        series.add(x[i],y[i]);
        series2.add(x[i], z[i]);

    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset=new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    dataset.addSeries(series2);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer=new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2=new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer2.setFillPoints(false);
```

In my example,i would like to fetch the labels from the xaxis array during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I realized i was trying to add labels to the XYSeriesRenderer.Should be added to the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.I also used a for loop to fetch the corresponding months from the xaxis array and display in the right x-axis position using their index.
The added code is:

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(x[i],xaxis[i]);
    }
```

Remember that it appears after the declaration of the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer.